# Java steering object with two wheel velocities

Tags: java, math, physics

Let's say I have a two wheeled object, where each wheel has an independent velocity (lWheelV and rWheelV for the left and right hand wheels respectively). The velocities of each of the wheels are limited to the range [-1, 1] (ie. between -1 and 1).

- If lWheelV = 1 & rWheelV = 1, the object moves forward
- If lWheelV = -1 & rWheelV = 1, the object turns left (counter-clockwise)
- If lWheelV = 0.5 & rWheelV = 1, the object will drive forward while slowly turning left
- If lWheelV = -1 & rWheelV = -1, the object will move backward.

This may be easier to visualise in the following image:

[image: object motion diagram]

What mathematics do I need to describe such an object, *and more importantly how could I implement software that would replicate this behavior in Java*.

Comment: Are asking for visualisation, algorythm, or code?
Can you be more formal?

Comment: Not visualization, the algorithm/code to figure out the new position.

Comment: To those voting to close, please understand that this is a real world problem that occurs frequently in robotics and physics. Such a system is not entirely trivial to implement without a firm understanding of the mathematics that underpin the system. The fact that the OP has made some effort to clearly describe the system should be counted in his favour

Comment: Whoa, this was edited into oblivion :)

Comment: Are you using a Scribbler robot by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on really a whole bunch of things like vehicle width, fps, etc...

However, some tips:

- To calculate the rotation for the vehicle in one frame, you can use the arctan function.

  ```
  float leftWheel = 1.0f;
  float rightWheel = 0.5f;
  float vehicleWidth = 1.0f;

  float diff = rightWheel - leftWheel;
  float rotation = (float) Math.atan2(diff, vehicleWidth);
  ```
- To determine the speed the vehicle is going to move along its axis, use this:

  ```
  float speedAlongAxis = leftWheel + rightWheel;
  speedAlongAxis *= 0.5f;
  ```
- To rotate the axis of the vehicle by the angle computed in the first tip:

  ```
  float axisX = ...;
  float axisY = ...;
  /* Make sure that the length of the vector (axisX, axisY) is 1 (which is 
   * called 'normalised')
   */

  float x = axisX;
  float y = axisY;

  axisX = (float) (x * Math.cos(rotation) - y * Math.sin(rotation));
  axisY = (float) (x * Math.sin(rotation) + y * Math.cos(rotation));
  ```
- To move the vehicle over the axis:

  ```
  float vehicleX = ...;
  float vehicleY = ...;

  vehicleX += axisX * speedAlongAxis;
  vehicleY += axisY * speedAlongAxis;
  ```
- A `normalise()` method looks like this:

  ```
  public float normalise()
  {
      float len = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
      x /= len;
      y /= len;
      return len;
  }
  ```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be Math.atan2(diff, vehicleWidth); ?

Comment: Please note that I'm not sure about the physics, but it will come close, I think. This might be a start.

Comment: @ConnerRuhl: Yup! Changed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you change your example so it doesn't use a vector class?

Comment: I think you ask this because of the `normalise()` call? Normalising a vector is scaling it that way that the length becomes one.

Comment: I cannot use a vector class, can you please rewrite the answer to exclude the code that uses vectors?

Comment: What does it mean when you have three dots (...)? Example: float axisX = ...;

Comment: You have to fill it in yourself. In the example axisX it is meant as declaration. `axisX` and others should be declared as class member.

Comment: But I don't understand what you are setting it equal to.

Comment: The axis is the direction (relative to (0,0)) in which the vehicle is pointing at. To start with set it to (1,0) to make your vehicle point to the right. Of course, you have to rotate the image of the vehicle depending on this axis.